# Is there a bug base for git?

Tags: git, git-p4

Found what appears to be a bug in the git-p4 integration tool and I can't seem to find any place to report it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Report the bug to the [Git mailing list](http://dir.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git).

Comment: IMHO a mailing list is not a suitable bug tracking system, but ... OK.

Comment: "You can also ask the Git community directly at our git@vger.kernel.org mailing list. Bug reports should be sent to this list." Quoted from the official website.